# Possible Memory/Ram utilization issue

Tags: memory

I currently have 16GB of RAM installed on my ASUS laptop (which is its max). however no matter what i am doing ie. editing video or photos I have only ever seen it use 3 GB. The computer recognized the new RAM and its all the same from the same lot number. How do i make sure my computer is configured to allow it to use all of the RAM. I am currently operating in windows 8.1 (64 bit). I have tried looking it up via Google but thus far have found no answers.

Comment: Is your laptop 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: why do you buy so much RAM if you don't run any software that takes advantage of it?

Answer (score -2):

Is your ram really good? You could boot a live Linux Mint (or Ubuntu or other) and it should have a "memtest" program in the boot menu that is good for testing RAM for errors & capacity, make a live usb/cd/dvd and give it a try to verify the ram first.

Are you running a version of Windows, and which one? [Windows 8 32-bit doesn't support more than 4GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_8) (shown as 3.xx GB). Only the 64-bit windows version do. If you used a 32-bit OS that supported PAE you could use all of your ram, Windows 32-bit doesn't but I use Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) and their 32-bit versions do support PAE and can use >4GB ram.

And, all hope is not lost if you're gung-ho on stickng with **Windows 8 32-bit**, according to [Matt Nawrocki on techrepublic.com](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/override-the-4gb-memory-barrier-on-32-bit-windows-81-systems/) you *may* be able to patch your windows kernel and "Override the 4GB memory barrier on 32-bit Windows 8.1 systems" using PAE.

Can you upgrade your Windows 8 32-bit to Windows 8 64-bit? You might be able to, with a 64-bit dvd of Windows, and hopefully using your original windows "key" without buying a new one. But it may be different depending on if you've got a "Retail" or a pre-installed "OEM" version. The answers from Microsoft are conflicting, this first one explicitly says you'll need to buy it, (as does a [tutorial about upgrading windows 8 from 32-bit to 64-bit on tomshardware.com](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1653310/upgrade-windows-bit-windows-bit.html) seemingly advising buying Windows 8 Pro )

Here's what [Microsoft says about upgrading from Windows 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8) 32-bit to 64-bit:

> #### Can I update from a 32-bit version of Windows to a 64-bit version of Windows 8.1?
>
> If your PC has a 64-bit capable processor (CPU) but is currently
>   running a 32-bit version of Windows, you can install a 64-bit version
>   of Windows 8.1, but **you'll need to buy it as a DVD and perform a clean
>   installation**. You won't be able to keep any files, settings, or apps
>   when you update from a 32-bit to a 64-bit version.
>
> Please note that the Windows 8.1 Pro Pack is used to upgrade from
>   Windows 8.1 to Windows 8.1 Pro, and isn't for cross-architecture
>   installs and doesn't include any media. If you want to change
>   architectures, **buy Windows 8.1 Pro**.
>
> For more info about what service packs are available, see Add
>   features.

And here's where where [Micfosoft says you can upgrade (and download an iso) using only a product key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only), but maybe only *if you bought windows*:

> Upgrade Windows with only a product key
>
> If you bought Windows 8.1 or Windows 8, you can download and install
>   Windows from this page using just your product key. You'll have the
>   option to install Windows now, later, or using media with an ISO file.

But, I spoke directly to a Microsoft "Answer Tech" and their answer supports the "Retail only" can download an iso, a pre-installed OEM Windows is different.

Comment: you don't pay extra for 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Really? I've never seen a windows that didn't want more money to upgrade. Do you have a reference about Windows 64-bit being free? Non-pirate I mean? I've updated my answer with what Microsoft says about upgrading from 32-bit to 64-bit

Comment: I said you don't pay extra - when you buy Windows, the product key is valid for 32-bit or 64-bit. "_Windows doesn't add a cost factor, since the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows both cost the same._" http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/taking-the-mystery-out-of-64-bit-windows

Comment: I've updated my answer with a very definitive response from Microsoft - if this fellow already has a 32-bit Windows 8 now, but wants a 64-bit Windows apparently he'll need to buy it.

Comment: Every supported version of Windows ( Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 8.1 ) license can be installed as 32-bit or 64-bit installation.  The only exception was `Windows XP 64-bit` which as a separate product SKU entirely and support schedule.

Comment: You hi-lighted the wrong part of the sentence "but you'll need to buy it **as a DVD and perform a clean installation.**", what it is saying is you can not perform a "upgrade" from 32 to 64 but will need to perform a "clean install". The DVD media contains both the 32 bit and the 64 bit install media. If you already own windows 8 no purchase is nessary, however you may need to obtain a DVD with the 64 bit installer if it came bundled with your computer (you can download the trial ISO at no charge from Microsoft which will accept your existing license and make it a full version)

Comment: That would be the "right" think for MS to do, and it makes for some very conflicting answers from Microsoft, they should have said "you **don't** have to buy Windows again, just download or beg/borrow/burn a dvd". I'll update with some new info, thanks.